# como replicar funções do jquery em javascript $(), hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

To criando um site, simples em javascript mais gostaria de automatizar a seleção elementos, e uma função pra esconder/mostrar os elementos. Mais acabo recebendo erro. Mais não entendi o porque.

Pra selecionar os elementos eu to usando

```
function $(par){
    return document.querySelector(par)
}
```

e para esconder:

```
function hide(e){
    return e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

a declaração fica:

```
$('.header').hide()
```

só que me é retornado o erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function
```

Comment: Está parecendo que vc não está chamando o jquery na sua página. Lógico, vc deve chamar antes de chamar o seu script js.

Comment: Ah ideia e refazer essas duas funcitons do jquery em javascript puro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para replicar as funções do Jquery você pode usar o prototype, por exemplo para fazer a função hide ficaria dessa forma:

```
Element.prototype.hide = function(){
   this.style.display = "none";
   return this;
}
```

Com isso você basicamente esta incluindo o metodo hide() dentro da classe Element.

Mais sobre prototypes: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: Brigado, funcionou! Vou pesquisar agora sobre prototype. Pra entender como funciona.